# How to add RequestBody example in NelmioApiDoc Bundle?

Tags: rest, symfony, nelmioapidocbundle

My annotations is:

```
     * @OA\RequestBody(
     *     required=true,
     *     @OA\JsonContent(
     *         @OA\Schema (
     *              type="object",
     *              @OA\Property(property="status", required=true, description="EventStatus", type="string"),
     *              @OA\Property(property="comment", required=false, description="Change Status Comment", type="string"),
     *              example={
     *                  "status": "test status",
     *                  "comment": "test comment"
     *              }
     *         )
     *     )
     * )
```

I tried to add an "example" key, but it didn't work.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/of5pj.png]

Comment: In your screenshot I see only 'id'. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: @StephanVierkant, what could be the problem ? 'id' - is a parameter from the path. i describe it like `@OA\Parameter(name="id", required=true, in="path", description="Event Id", @OA\Schema(type="integer", example=1))`, and by the way in this case, "example" key  is working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`example` key must be part of the `@OA\JsonContent` as below.

```
 * @OA\RequestBody(
 *     required=true,
 *     @OA\JsonContent(
 *         example={
 *             "status": "status",
 *             "comment": "comment"
 *         },
 *         @OA\Schema (
 *              type="object",
 *              @OA\Property(property="status", required=true, description="Event Status", type="string"),
 *              @OA\Property(property="comment", required=false, description="Change Status Comment", type="string"),
 *         )
 *     )
 * )
```

Answer (score 0):

With Attributes you must use the following:

```php
use OpenApi\Attributes as OA;

class ObjectController
{
    #[OA\RequestBody(
        required: true,
        content: new OA\JsonContent(
            type: Object::class,
            example: [
                "status" => "status",
                "comment" => "comment"
            ]
        )
    )]
}
```